# Can't get this class checked and added to my array for every answer of my quiz?

Tags: jquery, arrays, class

I want this function to add 1 to total for every time an input with the class .CA is selected. I can't make this work? I was trying to make this code push each selected input to my array and then read the length to get the total score of the player.

```
   var quiz = function () {
    total = 0;
    var arr=[];
    $('#submit').click(function () {

    var score= function () {
    var thischecked=$('.CA').is(':checked');
    if (thischecked) {
        arr.push(thischecked);
        total= arr.length;
        $('#points').text('Score: '+total);
            }
    else {
        $('#points').text('Score: ' +total);
            }
    };
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zach94/ckgcdrys/) for clarification if needed.

Comment: silly question but `arr` is an array declared loosely somewhere else, yes?

Comment: Yes it is, this function is inside the click function.

Comment: if the function is intended to be a handler, separate from the elements or any other some such binding - we're (stackOF) are not given enough visibility into how you expect this to work. from this perspective : you're jQuery'ing the DOM for any element whatsoever that matches, asking if its checked and then doing something entirely else no one has any visibility into. So, "Good Luck" or "make this question better."

Comment: crazy town.do a fiddle or codepen - otherwise, i modified it a little to prod you into the (a?) direction : 

`var quiz = function () {
    total = 0;
    var arr=[];
    $('#submit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // you're going to have to sort this out later homeboy.
        var thischecked=$('.CA').is(':checked');
        if (thischecked) {
            arr.push(thischecked);
            total= arr.length;
            $('#points').text('Score: '+total);
            }
        else {
        $('#points').text('Score: ' +total);
            }
    });
    }`

Comment: I added the fiddle as well with that edit but this works too, thanks.